# Will there be any unexpected side effects when I upgrade the Zen theme?

Tags: 7, upgrading, theming

I have installed the 7.x-5.6 theme and I want to upgrade to the 7.x-6 version. I have created 2 subthemes from it that I hardly use, and I hardly use the Zen theme itself - it is supposed to be base theme,not actually used in any case.

Is it okay for me just to disable and delete the base theme and the derived themes and install the 7.x-6.4 as though the previous ones were never installed in the first place?

PS. Are there any hidden downsides to uninstalling themes, like some stray database tables etc?

Comment: You need to look at the code changes yourself. Maybe some libraries paths or preprocess hooks changed and therefore your sub-themes may be affected by that. Normally you just replace the files without uninstalling and reinstalling the theme or module. Definitely test the update first in an different environment. It's definitely **not safe** to do that with your live site.

Comment: By default, we couldn't tell you if there will be unexpected consequences, because anything we could tell you would be expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Themes don't create their *own* database tables.

The changes about the theme status (enabled, default, theme settings) are stored in the `system` and `variable` tables, along with many other system settings, it's nothing you should be worried about.

Some themes are accompanied by a special module built especially for them, but Zen isn't one of those.

**Yes, you can disable and delete old Zen and its subthemes without consequences.** Set Bartik as default theme before removing old Zen out of your system.

It's good practice to backup files before deleting, it's up to you, at least check if there are any files you might want to keep, maybe logo images.

Then download and enable the latest Zen. Create the latest Zen subtheme using the latest Zen procedure.

The latest Zen theme structure and procedures are significantly different from the older versions. You'll have to install some bundles and other dependencies and learn how to build Sass through Gulp (if you want Sass)...

You might experience problems if you want to *keep* the old subthemes and make them work with new the Zen, but if you want to *start fresh* there aren't bad consequences if you remove old Zen and its subthemes and then install new Zen.

It's good to remember to clear (theme) cache when changing things like these, even though theme registry is rebuilt on visiting the Appearance page.

Comment: Do I really need SASS, LESS etc, or can I use plain CSS? I don't have the time to delve into a whole new area of web development. CSS alone will have to do for now.

Comment: You don't have to use Sass if you don't want to. You can probably just use layout classes to make use of what's available there, create your own CSS, include the files in subthemename.info and never deal with Sass. But remember that the `css` folder gets overwritten if you ever decide to turn on generating CSS from Sass, so it would be wise to create a different folder where you would store your custom CSS, and include that in the .info file. You can then ignore the installation steps needed for Gulp, styleguide etc.

Comment: What are the 'layout classes'? Are they a separate set of CSS files, or template files? I have done some reading on theming in general and Zen subthemes and understand the part about editing the .info files and pointing to different locations for the CSS files.

Comment: I haven't tried it without Sass, it's difficult to say what steps you might take, but AFAICT you can see `STARTERKIT/css/styles.css`. This is the CSS already generated from the base theme, ready to be used. You can search it for `layout` and see what's available, although I wouldn't change that too much, it already works, and you need more CSS expertise to create a new custom layout. You should create a custom css file in a different folder and add that to the .info file to override old and add new styles, don't change the existing styles.css and don't put your custom code into the css folder.